# Write on File UDP bytes received with python

Tags: python, sockets, udp, fpga

I'm working on a python program that will let me communicate with an FPGA sending me packets at about 109 MB/s via UDP. I have a problem right now that i'm willing to solve:

The FPGA sends me 1400 bytes per packet (binary) and I want to save those in a file. Right now this part of the code looks like this (it's the function called by a multiprocess instance):

```
filio = open('pack.bin',"wb")
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)    
sock.bind(('',int(udportr.get())))
start = "Starting..."
q.send(start)
t = Timer(1, lambda:q.send(a))
t.start()
a = 0
while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1400)     
    if checksave.get() == 1:
        filio.write(data)                        
    if t.is_alive():
        a +=1
    else:
        start_time = time.time()
        print a 
        t = Timer(1, lambda:q.send(a))  # q refers to a Pipe
        t.start()
        a = 0             
sock.close()
```

The problem is that when i toogle on the write on file after about 2 GB the rate slows down a lot reaching 30 MB/s. This happens only when i'm trying to save on file, otherwise the rate remains constant at ~ 109 MB/s.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2GB threshold might hint a hardware issue. What are you running this program on ?

When you write to a file, generally the data is not written directly to your hard drive, but rather to cache. This can be distributed between HDD cache, RAM, Swap, or any other fast memory (depending on your specific hardware and OS). The data is then copied (slowly) to the hard drive, in the background. This allows for *seemingly* quick disk write, but only works as long as there is free cache space.

Perhaps your system has ~2GB of available writing cache, and once this is filled up, your write speed is limited to your raw disk write speed. 30MB/s is not great for a HDD, but it could still be coherent.

If this is in fact the problem, the solution is upgrading your hardware. Can you add a SSD to write this file to ?
Otherwise, you can also compress the data before writing. This will reduce the amount you have to write, and so solve (or at least reduce) your current problem, but it will have a consequent cost on processing power usage.

Comment: It's an old linux Server with 8GB of RAM and 250 GB of HDD, unfortunately i can't upgrade the HDD or add an SSD because the server it's not mine, but i could definetely try the saving on newer pc to see if it's actually an hardware problem. Thank you for the quick answer.